# How to refresh view in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In a web application i have a user that belongs to one or more accounts and in each account there are transactions when user changes his account i need to get new transactions that belongs to that account.What i have done is to make a directive that can make that call till now every thing is working fine except that i have to hit refresh button to get new data (transaction). my first idea is to get current user location and redirects him to the same location to refresh data but that dose not work.

```
.directive("accountslist",  function(AccountService, Session, $location){
        return{
            restrict:'E',
            replace:'true',
            template:
            '<select ng-change="SetAcc()" ng-model="MyAcc" ng-options="Acc for Acc in userAccounts"></select>',
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.userAccounts = AccountService.getAccounts();

                $scope.SetAcc = function(){
                    var userMail = Session.get_user_mail();
                    var setUser = AccountService.SetUserAccount($scope.MyAcc, userMail);
                    setUser.then(function(response){
                         //http call with new data
                         CategoryService.getCategories();
                        //here i need to updata the view
                    },
                    function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                };
            }
     };

    });
```

Her is an example of setting the categories in categories controller where i need to do the same thing when i change the account.

```
   $scope.getCategories =function(){
    $scope.categories.getCategories().success(function(data){
        $scope.categories.categories = data; 
        $scope.allCategoriesSum();
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers){alert(status);}); 
}
```

Comment: $location does nothing if you lett it go to the same location, since it is already there. It is not entirely clear to me what you want to do. If you want to retrieve something like the userAccounts again, make a function out of it and call that again. If you want to lett the rest of the page know that it should do something I recommend $broadcast  or $emit. It give a much cleaner design.

Comment: when user change to new account i need to recall HTTP requests to get new data that can be done if i hit refresh button as script loads again if i call the same resources again i will end up duplicating my code

Comment: Not if you wrap that code in a function. Something like: var loadMyDate = function(){service.get();}. In your controller you call that function the first time, and when the button is clicked call it again.

Comment: I have made that but the ui dose not update

Comment: in your example I don't see anything that would do that. Am I missing something?

Comment: i will post the edit now. And how i would set the scope of the controller for example transaction controller to that new HTTP call

Comment: what is the status of this? Is you issue solved?

Comment: @apairet Yes i have used broadcasting.

Comment: @apairet move your answer from comment section and i will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function "getTransactions()" in you AccountService retrieving all transactions for an account from the server, you could do:

```
.directive("accountslist",  function(AccountService, Session, $location){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        replace:'true',
        template:
        '<select ng-change="SetAcc()" ng-model="MyAcc" ng-options="Acc for Acc in userAccounts"></select>',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.userAccounts = AccountService.getAccounts();

            $scope.SetAcc = function(){
                var userMail = Session.get_user_mail();
                AccountService.SetUserAccount($scope.MyAcc, userMail)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return AccountService.getTransactions($scope.MyAcc, userMail);
                    })
                    .then(function (transactions) {
                        $scope.transactions = transactions;
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });                   
            };
        }
 };

});
```

Comment: The problem is that directive can not see transactions controller scope also i have to update categories controller the same problem will appear

Comment: I think you need broadcasting. So in stead of calling the service call $scope.$emit('accountlist-account-changed'); and in your controller listen to $scope.$on('accountlist-account-changed',function(event){// call the reshresh };.

Comment: I have update the question and i will search on broadcasting.